# SelectByAttribute is not working (ArcGIS, Arcpy. Python script) -

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, feature-layer

My script is below. 
I use to file from filegeodatabase to select all of rows (in a loop, one by one) to create a simple map and export it to jpeg.

For some reason, once I updated my script to run outside of arcmap (so I am not using reference to layer in arcmap now), the exported jpegs are focused on just a random spot rather than the feature location.

Any ideas what I need to update for it to run again?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"H:\NetworkAnalyst\TopologyVer4\mb_outputs.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"H:\NetworkAnalyst\RoadSegments.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r'H:\NetworkAnalyst\TopologyVer4\mb_outputs.gdb\T_Err_BridTunn',"lyrBridTun")

#Function returns unique values for specified field (all works fine)
def unique_values(table, field):
       with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
            return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

lstBT = list()
lstBT = unique_values(r'lyrBridTun', 'OriginObjectID')

for each_f in lstBT:
    whereClause = 'OriginObjectID = %s' %each_f
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(r'lyrBridTun', "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    df.scale = 1000
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    str_name = str(each_f)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"H:\NetworkAnalyst\BridgeTunn_" + str_name, data_frame = "PAGE_LAYOUT", resolution = 300)
    print each_f, "Bridge Tunnel done"
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not `import arcpy` or set `mxd` anywhere. In any event I think you should cut it down to just what is inside your `for` loop because to get them all working you need to get the first one working first.

Comment: Outside of ArcMap how are you creating/opening the document and accessing the data frame? Even though you're making a layer it's possibly not associated with your data frame so ArcMap is confused when you say "Zoom To Selected" as it can't find anything selected to set its extent... I think we need a bit more code before the loop to diagnose this.

Comment: PolyGeo, I have updated that part. It was there but I thought to simplify by excluding it.

Comment: Michael Miles-Stimson, I think you are right! hm.. then I need to find a way to add layer to my map in modelbuilder and save it as I run script in my model. thank you!

Comment: I cannot see a role for ModelBuilder in what you are trying to do.  I think you'll be better to start with a code snippet like the one at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/88675/115 and then build it up to what you need by adding just a line or two between tests.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using data-driven pages? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/what-are-data-driven-pages-.htm

Answer (score 1):

Though I would recommend using data-driven pages to accomplish your goal (that is, unless you plan to extend the functionality of your code), your current approach is only missing one little piece: You need to reference the layer from your map, rather than creating a new layer object (that isn't in your map) from the feature class.

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"H:\NetworkAnalyst\TopologyVer4\mb_outputs.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"H:\NetworkAnalyst\RoadSegments.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]

lyrName = 'WhateverTheLayerIsCalledInYourMap'
layerOfInterest = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, lyrName, df)

fieldOfInterest = 'OriginObjectID'

#Function returns unique values for specified field (all works fine)
def unique_values(table, field):
       with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
            return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})

lstBT = list()
lstBT = unique_values(layerOfInterest, fieldOfInterest)

for each_f in lstBT:
    whereClause = '{} = {}'.format(fieldOfInterest, each_f)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layerOfInterest, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    df.scale = 1000
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    str_name = str(each_f)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"H:\NetworkAnalyst\BridgeTunn_" + str_name, data_frame="PAGE_LAYOUT", resolution = 300)
    print each_f, "Bridge Tunnel done"
```

If the layer isn't already in the map, you would need to do something with
`arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df...)`, depending on file names and what you want the layer named in the map.